# Snowflake ingest manager - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_asdict' Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

My objective is to use Snowpipe REST API with automation through AWS Lambda as described in the documentation. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-rest-lambda

I created the function with proper key-pair authentication and S3 connections along with deploying the lambda function on AWS.

For every lambda function there is a handler in which you describe your S3 locations and other stuff. To ingest a file uploaded on S3 to Snowflake, we create an external stage in Snowflake that shows what files are ready to load to Snowflake. I tested my connection and everything is working fine. All the connections are correct.

The handler function is:

```
def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
    bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = record['s3']['object']['key']

    print("Bucket: " + bucket + " Key: " + key)
    # List of files in the stage specified in the pipe definition
    # wrapped into a class
    staged_file_list = ['customer_1.csv']
    staged_file_list.append(StagedFile(key, None))

    print('Pushing file list to ingest REST API')
    resp = ingest_manager.ingest_files(staged_file_list)
```

Above you can see `staged_file_list` where you list your files that you want to load and the notation to do that is given here:

[image: Snowflake documentation] https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-rest-lambda

Th keyword is 'relative' - Now the whole URL looks like -

[image: S3 whole url]

This looks correct to me as I tried to monitor the logs of the lambda function and there you can see the proper bucket and key values as expected, but I am facing an error for which I have not been able to find the documentation or resolution. The error is as below:

[image: error]

I have tried to restructure the directory to properly aim towards the correct S3 bucket and file name but nothing worked. It seems to me like a bug in ingest manager. I look forward to your input in where I could have gone wrong.

Expectation - I upload 'customer_1.csv' to my S3, this triggers the lambda function, which in turns loads the file to Snowflake table.

Comment: The `stage_files_list` is relative to the path used in the external stage creation. How does your external stage looks like? Also what happens if you try this code? `staged_files = [StagedFile('customer_1.csv', None)]`. Do you still get the same error?